# How can I run ssh-add on demand? Can it act as SSH_ASKPASS?

Tags: ssh, password, ssh-agent, access-control, user-interface

I want to ssh from `user@local` to `user@remote` several times per day with an encrypted SSH key, a situation which `ssh-agent` handles with a good trade-off between security and usability.

I'd also like to not have to remember to run `ssh-add` before `ssh`'ing—I'd rather be asked for my password the first time I need it, and then have it automatically be remembered for, say, eight hours.

So: I think I want to use `ssh-add` roughly where I think `$SSH_ASKPASS` is used, except `ssh-add` doesn't feed `ssh` the password it wants, as far as I understand.  Is my understanding correct?  If so, the obvious solution seems to be writing a script which asks for a password, runs `ssh-add` and then echoes the password back to `ssh`. Does this sound like the right approach?  Is there a better way?  If not, do you have a pointer or two to get started on this script?

(I use ssh from linux console, xterm and emacs `*shell*` buffers; X-wise the solution doesn't need to do anything fancy.)

Comment: `SSH_ASKPASS` is used only if `ssh` is not run a terminal and the `DISPLAY` variable is set to something. Otherwise your approach would be the right one.

Answer (score 3):

I was just looking for essentially the same solution, and found two that look useful under two different assumptions:

- Michael J. Schultz solved his problem with this by writing a [shell alias for ssh](http://beyond-syntax.com/blog/2012/01/on-demand-ssh-add/). It uses

  ```
  ssh-add -l > /dev/null || ssh-add
  ```

  to check if ssh-agent has any loaded keys, and if there are none, run ssh-add. He notes that the way he wrote his solution fits his use case, but won't fit everyone's.
- Raúl Benencia wrote a Python script named [`odsa`](http://kalgan.cc/posts/2013-11-24-On_demand_ssh-add.html) to automatically figure out which of your keys are needed for a given host and load them into ssh-agent.

Answer (score 2):

The way I handle the same requirement is similar as what Mike wrote about Michael:

```
~/bin/sshmyvps

#!/bin/bash
if ! ssh-add -l|grep -q vpsaccess
then
    ssh-add -t 2h ~/ssh-keys/vpsaccess.key
fi
ssh  myuser@myserver.mydomain.net
```

The main difference being that I don't look for just **any** loaded keys but only for a specific one and then leaving it valid for a restricted time only.

Answer (score 1):

Since [OpenSSH 7.2](https://www.openssh.com/txt/release-7.2) there is the client config option `AddKeysToAgent`.

Add this to your `~/.ssh/config` file:

```
AddKeysToAgent yes
```

From the release notes:

- ssh(1): Add an AddKeysToAgent client option which can be set to
  'yes', 'no', 'ask', or 'confirm', and defaults to 'no'.  When
  enabled, a private key that is used during authentication will be
  added to ssh-agent if it is running (with confirmation enabled if
  set to 'confirm').